# Design showing seriously messed up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've had to work on a fairly complex design ( http://scoding.com/eyal/ ) because of its layout and shape, finally done it, all happy - until I checked on IE, it's seriously messed up, but why is that? Why is the container not centered? I have looked on google for some answers, and didn't find anything that could help, ANY HELP would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of IE did you check?

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I've heard that phrase..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE is rendering the page in 'quirks mode' (if you press F12 in IE you'll see the 'document mode' defaults to quirks).

Set a doctype like:

```
<!doctype html>
```

And all will be well!

For bonus points, run it through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix the errors it flags!

Comment: Well you only have [3 errors now](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fscoding.com%2Feyal%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), which is great!    
You've got a rogue </style> (which can be removed), EditURI seems to be something to do with wordpress so you can remove it, and the <br clear="all"> can be replace with <br style="clear:both;" />

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons that every web designer hates IE.. ;-)

Unfortunately, there is no magic answer for you. You have to get the right tools and test every browser you want to support and fix the CSS for every broswer.

Not all browsers interpret CSS in the same way.  But IE is the one most people will have problems with.

Hints:

Try using a CSS framework. [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) or [CSS960](http://960.gs/) are among the most popular IMO.  With a framework, you have a better chance of having the same result in every browser.

For IE, you can download the [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359).  It's like Firefox's Firebug but for IE. It is essential to debug CSS problems in IE.

Take note that if you want to support IE6,7,8 you will have to test them all :-(  Because you will probably have different results in each version.

If you use JavaScript, I highly recommend jQuery.  Never write "native" JavaScript code since it is interpreted differently in each browser.  jQuery takes care of that and ensures that your code will be cross-browser compatible.

Good luck

Comment: You only need to download the developer toolbar for IE6/7. IE8+ includes it already.